# Elegent way to get dockerized API to connect with dockerized Mysql Database and create schema automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices

**Problem:**
2 services, both running in separate docker containers

- Mysql DB (container name: mysqldb, network: my-custom-network)
- Api service that supports retrieving and writing data to Mysql service

Now I create a custom docker network `my-custom-network` with `driver: bridge` and connect both services to it.

**Intention:**
Also I set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` so that when the api service is started and it connects with the DB first time it automatically creates the table. **But this doesn't happen.**

**What happens is this:**

- Using the mysql image I start the DB container, setting all required passwords and users as environment variables. So this is container is up successfully.
- Now when I try to build the image for my API server using the docker file, then while building it tries to connect with the database and it says `HostNotFoundException: mysqldb not known`. This is probably because mysql container is running on my custom network but while building the image docker doesn't know which network to use (**I am not sure of this.**  So it fails.

**Workaround that I did**

- set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `none` so that while building the api image, docker does not try to contact the mysql service.
- Then image is successfully build. I run the api container on same `my-custom-network` and the container is up successfully.
- Now when I try to write data to DB, **an exception occurs saying dbname.tablename doesn't exists**. Which means tables are not automatically creating when making first connection to the database as `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `none`.

**What I want**

I want some way that tables etc are created automatically and the docker image also builds successfully. But I don't know how to do it and hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building an image and running a container are 2 very different things.

At build time (when you build an image based on a Dockerfile for example) there is no network setup to be done because there is nothing running. Only Docker building an image. So when you build your java image, only create the jar and that's it.

For running the containers I suggest using docker-compose. It makes your life a lot easier. Your java container should use something like a `wait-for.sh` script to wait for the database to become available. There are tons of examples on internet for such scripts. If you can't find such a script then for now just manually start the database container and wait for it to finish starting and then start the other container.

The main point is: the java application creates the data model at runtime (when the container starts) and not at build time (when the image is created).

Comment: Hi, you are right but i think u didn't get the question. Problem is not that api service is trying to connect to database when it is not fully available. Problem is it is not able to find and I don't know why. Even if I manually start and wait for database to become available, I would still get hostnotfound exception :( Don't know why

Comment: But your point of creating only a jar while building the image has high chances working. Will try and revert back.

Comment: make sure you can actually connect to the database from outside the container. the database should listen on all interfaces, not only on the local 127.0.0.1. You can try to map the port 3306 on the host and try to connect a database client to it

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a test failing at build time because of the property. If that is correct, you can just add a properties with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` in src/test/resources.

Alternative is to add a properties file in the container beside the jar with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` after building it with none. It should be read at runtime and override the one in the jar.

Comment: Will try this for sure.